# How to get link in iFrame without class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to find a link inside an iframe using jquery.
This example of his scripts:

```
<body>
    <iframe src='content.html' framborder='0'>
        <html>
            <body>
                <div class="afk">
                    <a href='index.html' target='_blank'>
                        <p>Text Here</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>

    <iframe src='content.html' framborder='0'>
        <html>
            <body>
                <div class="afk">
                    <a href='index-2.html' target='_blank'>
                        <p>Text Here</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</body>
```

how do I get the value of the "href" of the link inside the iframe?

Comment: is your iframe in the same domain and subdomain as of the parent window?

Comment: @prasun just on domain. But in this case, i'm use localhost for testing.

Comment: You can use `$('iframe').contents().find('.afk a').attr('href')`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can you provide an example script?

Comment: @RoadName look at the above comment

Comment: @ArunPJohny from your script, I got the results 'undefined'

Comment: @RoadName you need to run the script only after the contents of teh iframe is loaded

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes, the content is already available for this execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
    //select frames
    var iframes = jQuery('iframe');

    $.each(iframes, function(i, iframe){
//this gives access to the window object of iframe
     childWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
      //now fire your selector query here
     console.log(childWindow.document.querySelector("div a").href); 
//or console.log(childWindow document.querySelector("div a").getAttribute("href"));
    })
```

Comment: i am assuming that you have only one iframe, if you have multiple you may want to modify iframe selector

Answer (score 0):

First you must wait a iframe is loaded, and if the iframe src have permissions, you can travel the dom of your iframe like as another page dom.

```
$('#myiframeid').load(function(){
  $(this).contents().find('a').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

Comment: what if not to use 'id'?

Comment: you can get an array of jquery used only 'iframe' tag. ej.: $('iframe') and use a specific one with get - $('iframe').get(0).load(function(){ /*some thing*/ }); or loop over all iframe tags in your html with: $('iframe').each(function(){ console.log(this); });